# How to troubleshoot: AAPT: error: is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Android dev and am working on my first app.  I have been running into trouble trying to get an image view set up with my own image (stock photos on studio are working fine), and am getting the following error:

AAPT: error: '/home/joshua/AndroidStudioProjects/WSC/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/wsc_foreground.png' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

I have researched around to even try to understand what this error is saying, and I think it is having trouble linking some file/resource?

I uploaded a .jpg using the add image asset option in android studio.  I added a color background to the image, which was a hex number I selected.

I am not getting any errors or warnings until I build, at which point the build fails.

**Can someone please explain:

1. What this error means.
2. How to troubleshoot this.
3. Where my mistake lies.**

I have attached the (hopefully sufficiently) relevant XML code.

Here is the image view inside of my fragment_first.xml, which is inside layout:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wsc_image"
        android:layout_width="930dp"
        android:layout_height="585dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/wsc_image_description"
        android:src="/home/joshua/AndroidStudioProjects/WSC/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/wsc_foreground.png"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textview_first"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textview_first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_first"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

I don't have an XML for the wsc_foreground.png, but do have a wsc.xml.  I tried adding the full path in the wsc.xml for wsc_foreground.png, but this did not change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/wsc_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="/home/joshua/AndroidStudioProjects/WSC/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/wsc_foreground.png"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

My apologies if this is a dumb question and/or not clear.  Please let me know in the comments if I need to clarify any of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I tried to add an image and got the same error... after an hour I realised that I had missed @ sign before drawable and then I used "" instead of "/" in the naming!

Answer (score 1):

Joshua, Since it's been a while you likely have already figured this out, but the issue might be that you're using the absolute path.

instead of

```
/home/joshua/AndroidStudioProjects/WSC/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/wsc_foreground.png
```

try (notice no file extension)

```
@mipmap/wsc_foreground
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott.  It has been a while, but what ended up working for me was deleting and re-adding the image into the project.  I can't remember if I tried without a file extension or not.  Thanks for the reply anyway, if it worked I would select best answer, but I have not way to verify this anymore sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Just now i faced same kind of error and after 45 mins of debugging found out this is a very silly mistake.

android:background="E7E7E7"
Error thrown: AAPT: error: E7E7E7 is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

*Answer:
android:background="#E7E7E7"(i missed # symbol).*

Joshua this might not be useful for you now as i was replying very late.
This can be helpful for someone else in some other part of the world.

Answer (score 0):

```
AAPT: error: is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color
```

Today I face this error.

Now I solved this problem.

I saw `webview id` in the layout is red color.
I think something happened. then I notice my `webview id` is wrong. I wrote `android:id/"myWebView"`

Then i wrote `android:id="@+id/myWebView"`

Then I run the app. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, copy any image from your laptop or pc and paste it to the drawable folder.
rename it to a short name as example myprofile.jpg/png i don't know.
change the src attribute in the ImageView to android:src="@drawable/myprofile"
also you can set a background color, in my case i set the background color Black.
then relaunch your device, it will be solved.